# Error: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views__ViewImports' (CS0101) [Prerendering]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, single-page-application

I'm building an ASP.NET web app from the ground up. It was working I added "asp-prerender-data" to the `Index.cshtml` file. JavaScript is not loading, only showing 'Loading...' on the Webpage.

VS code is now populating the following errors:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/david/OneDrive/workspace/Prerendering/Views/Home/Index.cshtml__virtual.cs",
    "owner": "csharp",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views_Home_Index' (CS0101) [Prerendering]",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 34
}
```

```xml
<app id="spa" asp-prerender-module = "ClientApp/boot-server" asp-prerender-data=" new { IsAdministrator = true, cookies = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies}">
    Loading...
</app>
```